# Red Hat 5.4 - Add time to bashrc

Tags: linux, redhat, bashrc

I am trying to add the current time to my bash in Redhat. I'd like it to read:

[user@hostname 01:01:01 ~] and obviously be relative to when the bash prompt was placed there.

Any ideas if this is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `PROMPT_COMMAND` found [here](http://divby0.blogspot.se/2008/09/howto-timestamp-your-bash-prompt.html)?

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n \[\$(date +%H:%M:%S)\]"
PS1=" "$PS1"\[\e]30;\u@\h\a\]"
```

Bear in mind that it won't give the time stamp for the current command, but the one before.